# @vectorize, OpenCV & Saturation image processing algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, numba

I am currently working on an image processing project in python, using cv2 and numba. up until now, all modification functions (brightness, contrast, exposure) could be written with a simple vectorize function as follows:

```
@vectorize([uint8(uint8,int32)])
def bright(value, b): return min(max(value + b, 0), 255)
```

Here is the problem: I now want to implement a saturation function, but the @vectorize decorator makes it such that the different color channels are dealt with seperately, which I do not want.

My question is: is there a way to tell numba not to split up the RGB channels for each pixel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it necessary? What's the actual calculation you want to perform? You mention you use OpenCV, yet your brightness function is basically reinventing what a single call to `cv2.add` could achieve...

Comment: Convert your image to HSV. Process only the V channel with your contrast processing. Then recombine and convert back to RGB.